# Run a maven webapp in a docker container

Tags: maven, docker, tomcat7

I'm trying to build a simple web app with Maven and run with Tomcat7, inside a Docker container.

This is my structure:

```
- Dockerfile
- pom.xml
- src/main/webapp/index.hmtl
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8

# Install maven
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y maven

WORKDIR /code

# Prepare by downloading dependencies
ADD pom.xml /code/pom.xml

# Adding source, compile and package into a fat jar
ADD src /code/src
RUN ["mvn", "package"]

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["mvn", "tomcat7:run"]
```

I'm building the Docker image with

```
docker build -t webapp-example .
```

and try to run it with

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 webapp-example
```

But apparently it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Got any error in your log?

Comment: could you try and run using `docker run -ti --rm -p 8080:8080 webapp-example` and paste the details here ?

Comment: I had no errors, the logs are normal as running `mvn tomcat7:run` out of a container. @GauravJ for some reason, with your command, my application is running! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you shared running using tty and interactive flag like following solves your problem,

`docker run -ti --rm -p 8080:8080 webapp-example`

That is because your base image is [java:8](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/) which is primarily created to run application in front mode (with -ti flag) or compile only in -d mode.

Also, since maven is build tools and should not be used to run application, you should,

1. Create you webapp using maven:latest image.
2. Deploy it separately as tomcat container using official [tomcat image](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Since I'm new to Docker and not totally sure how to do things yet, I suppose these 2 steps should be combined by Docker compose, am I right?

Comment: It depends on how you would run your application. Generally, creating war files and deploying it are two different steps. If you are using jenkins, then it would be 2 jobs/build pipeline. If you still want to do it together, docker-compose is a good option.